# How to get relationed models data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

I have the model `User`, `Status` and `Like`.
Where:

`User` has many `Statuses`

`Status` has many `Likes`

How can I get the `count` of `likes` that a User has of all status?
For example, user has 2 statuses that each of these has 10 likes. How can I get the total number? (20likes) ?

Comment: What do you mean by relacioned? I thought it was a word I didn't know, but I googled it and it came up with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Like.joins(status: :user).where(status: { user: user }).count
```

Another option is to add

```
has_many :likes, through: :statuses
```

on your `User` model. Then you can access a user's statuses likes with:

```
user.likes
```

and count them with:

```
user.likes.count
```

You might want to rename the association to something more descriptive, since this isn't actually a user's likes. Check out the rails documentation for `has_many` to see how to do this.

Comment: the second method doesn't work. :(  That’s a pity! this is so clean

Comment: @IgorMartins I added a third option, which is probably better.